# How to compute a loop in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

If two nodes point to each other in a neural network, how would you prevent the network from being stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. During which phase of a neural network are you referring to? Learning or in use? And with what algorithm?

Comment: @Alejandro Just simply when the network is computing some inputs, say that two hidden nodes connect to each other

Comment: Lets assume a feedforward/backprop network. This is usually done by matrix operations so the concept of a loop here is a misnomer. During training, however, one usually adjusts the network until a certain error is achieved. Using different structures may not yield good results upon training, but looking at an RNN for example, the recursive structure performs quite well on some applications. Which is why this question is really quite broad because so many things can influence training/using of a neural network

Comment: @Alejandro Hmm alright I'll read up a bit more so I can understand what I'm asking better

Comment: I think the element you're missing is that nodes of different layers are connected, not in the same layer.

Answer (score 2):

The methodology you seem to be envisioning is one of:

```
calculate a node's new output
for each node that takes that node as input:
    calculate that node's new output
```

and if there are any loops in the connections between nodes, this will indeed cause an infinite loop.

Node updates should be made 'simultaneously' thus:

```
for each node in nodes
  read inputs
  calculate and store new output as node->new_output
for each node in nodes
  node->output = node->new_output
```

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned in the comments, there are several factors which may influence how long (possibly infinitely long) a neural network takes to train. If an algorithm such as backpropagation is used, which consists of series of matrix operations, taking derivatives, and adjusting neuron weights, the concept of a "loop" in a misnomer, and ditto for feedforward. Training a network is usually achieved once a desired error is attained on a test set. Since backprop is a non-convex optimization method, it is likely that in a particular setup of the neurons, such as having them refer back to a previous one, as opposed to being bipartite, training may never finish because the desired error level is never achieved and the algorithm may be stuck at a local minimum.

Some other neural network models such as RNNs which have an innate recursive structure, perform quite well in certain areas, but training them is not as straightforward as simply performing a backpropagation, so the "infinite loop" aspect is also not so easy to apply here.

Comment: This does not answer the question.